# Subprocess Popen command runs but doesn't actually do anything

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, portforwarding

We're trying to port-forward in python by running cmd commands with subprocess, like so:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

port = 57123
username = "user"
password = "password"
remote_ip = "10.1.1.110"
cmd = subprocess.Popen(f'ssh -f -N -L {port}:127.0.0.1:{port} {username}@{remote_ip}', stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
cmd.stdin.write(password+'\n')
cmd.stdin.flush()
```

This code runs without error, but it doesn't actually do anything. The port is not forwarded. `cmd.stderr` is also empty (`None`). Any idea what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Try printing `stdout` as well.

Comment: `stdout` also returns `None`

Comment: Try ending the password with `\r` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Using `\r` did not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know what else is going on, but `ssh` will only read a password from a TTY. So you'll have to make its stdin a PTY. Or better yet, use an ssh key instead of a password.